# Ошибка при выключении tomcat 9 memory leak

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Подскажите как исправить?

```
04-Apr-2018 22:52:23.289 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
04-Apr-2018 22:52:23.289 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@10/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:64)
 java.base@10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
 java.base@10/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@10/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
04-Apr-2018 22:52:23.289 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgeknc9u14kipx21b5y3it|20fda773]-AdminTaskTimer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@10/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:553)
 java.base@10/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
04-Apr-2018 22:52:23.289 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgeknc9u14kipx21b5y3it|20fda773]-HelperThread-#0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
04-Apr-2018 22:52:23.289 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgeknc9u14kipx21b5y3it|20fda773]-HelperThread-#1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
04-Apr-2018 22:52:23.289 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hgeknc9u14kipx21b5y3it|20fda773]-HelperThread-#2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@10/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:683)
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>by.example</groupId>
<artifactId>crm</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>CRM</name>

<properties>
    <junit.version>3.8.1</junit.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.2.16.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.connector.version>5.1.45</mysql.connector.version>
    <servlet.version>4.0.0</servlet.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <c3p0.version>5.2.15.Final</c3p0.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${c3p0.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>crm</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо закрывать пул конекшенов, вызывая метод close() для класса com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource. В Вашем случае, это необходимо делать (зарегистрировать) в ServletContextListener. [Ответ дан в таком же вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24185091/memomy-leaks-in-a-java-web-service-using-hibernate)

Comment: Если возможно скиньте пример как это реализовать (в проекте используется hibernate)